# Почему strip_tags() не удаляет тег?

Tags: php

Не могу понять что я делаю не так, символы вроде бы перепроверил:

```
$a = '<p>W</p>';
echo strip_tags($a, '<p>');
```

https://ideone.com/YnyaDI

Comment: неужто в мануале об этом не написано? Быстрее же там прочитать....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй параметр теги которые удалять не нужно, т.е. просто:

```
$a = '<p>W</p>';
echo strip_tags($a);
```

Если писать:

```
 strip_tags($a, '<p>');
```

то удалять все теги, кроме `<p>`

[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php)